# JPA - TypedQuery with Left Join and Count

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hql

I've been trying to construct a SQL below, using TypedQuery with Criteria Builder:

```
select
        a.id,
        a.numeroAvisoPagamento,
        a.industria_id,
        a.varejo_id,
        a.dataAvisoPagamento,
        a.statusAvisoPagamento,
        a.dataUploadArquivo,
        a.dataImportacaoArquivo,
        a.dataConciliacaoAviso,
        count(c.avisoPagamento_id) as qtdeNotas, 
    from
        AvisoPagamento a  
    left join
        LoteAvisoPagamento l 
            ON l.codigoAviso = a.numeroAvisoPagamento 
    left join
        Cobranca c 
            ON c.avisoPagamento_id = l.id 
    where
        a.industria_id = ? 
        and a.varejo_id = ? 
        and a.numeroAvisoPagamento = ? 
        and a.dataAvisoPagamento between ? and ? 
    group by
        a.id,
        a.numeroAvisoPagamento,
        a.numeroAvisoPagamento,
        a.industria_id,
        a.varejo_id,
        a.dataAvisoPagamento,
        a.statusAvisoPagamento,
        a.dataUploadArquivo,
        a.dataImportacaoArquivo,
        a.dataConciliacaoAviso
```

**Models**

**AvisoPagamento**

```
@Entity(name = "AvisoPagamento")
public class AvisoPagamento {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "avisoPagamento", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CobrancaAvisoPagamento> cobrancas;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "avisoPagamento", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("dataAcao ASC")
@JsonIgnore(accept={"AvisoPagamentoController.*"})
private List<LogAvisoPagamento> logAvisoPagamento;
}
```

**LoteAvisoPagamento**

```
@Entity(name = "LoteAvisoPagamento")
public class LoteAvisoPagamento {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Long codigoAviso;

}
```

**Cobranca**

```
public class Cobranca {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "avisoPagamento_id")
@JsonIgnore(accept = { "CobrancaLoteController.listaCobrancas", "CobrancaAdmController.*",
        "ConciliacaoController.*", "CobrancaIndController.*" })
private LoteAvisoPagamento avisoPagamento;
}
```

I have two problems:

1. The entities LoteAvisoPagamento and AvisoPagamento , there is no relationship between them so I "forced" union with two columns: ON LoteAvisoPagamento.codigoAviso = AvisoPagamento.numeroAvisoPagamento. Works fine with SQL Native.
2. I need to count records from Table Cobranca so I used count(c.avisoPagamento_id)

I would like to rewitre this SQL to TypedQuery and CriteriaBuilder so I tried this:

```
//Create Criteria Builder
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        //Create CriteriaQuery da Classe AvisoPagamento
        final CriteriaQuery<AvisoPagamento> query = builder.createQuery(AvisoPagamento.class);
        //Create from
        final Root<AvisoPagamento> rootAviso = query.from(AvisoPagamento.class);

        //Left Join Lote Aviso Pagamento
        Root<LoteAvisoPagamento> rootLoteAviso = query.from(LoteAvisoPagamento.class);

        final Predicate predicateLeftJoin = builder.equal(rootAviso.get("numeroAvisoPagamento"), rootLoteAviso.get("codigoAviso"));

        //Conditions
        Predicate predicateAvisoPagamento = builder.and();

        //Join Selects
        Predicate criteria = builder.conjunction();
        criteria = builder.and(criteria, predicateAvisoPagamento);
        criteria = builder.and(criteria, predicateLeftJoin);

        //Passou a Industria
        if (industria != null){
             predicateAvisoPagamento = builder.and(predicateAvisoPagamento, builder.equal(rootAviso.get("industria"), industria));
        }
        //Passou o Varejo
        if (varejo != null){
            predicateAvisoPagamento = builder.and(predicateAvisoPagamento, builder.equal(rootAviso.get("varejo"), varejo));
        }
        //Passou o numero do Aviso
        if (numeroAviso != null){
            predicateAvisoPagamento = builder.and(predicateAvisoPagamento, builder.equal(rootAviso.get("numeroAvisoPagamento"), numeroAviso));
        }

        //Passou as Datas De e Ate
        if (dataDe != null && dataAte != null){
            predicateAvisoPagamento = builder.between(rootAviso.<Date>get("dataAvisoPagamento"), dataDe , dataAte);
        }


        //TypedQuery eh mais robusto, a checagem de tipo é feito na compilacao, eliminando alguns
        //tipos de erros
        final TypedQuery<AvisoPagamento> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(
            query.select(rootAviso).distinct(true)
            .where( criteria )
            .orderBy(builder.desc(rootAviso.get("dataConciliacaoAviso")))
        );


        //return List
        final List<AvisoPagamento> results = typedQuery.getResultList();

        return results;
```

Then JPA generated this SQL:

```
select
        distinct avisopagam0_.id as id1_9_,
        avisopagam0_.arquivoFisico as arquivoF2_9_,
        avisopagam0_.dataAvisoPagamento as dataAvis3_9_,
        avisopagam0_.dataConciliacaoAviso as dataConc4_9_,
        avisopagam0_.dataImportacaoArquivo as dataImpo5_9_,
        avisopagam0_.dataUploadArquivo as dataUplo6_9_,
        avisopagam0_.industria_id as industri9_9_,
        avisopagam0_.numeroAvisoPagamento as numeroAv7_9_,
        avisopagam0_.statusAvisoPagamento as statusAv8_9_,
        avisopagam0_.usuario_id as usuario10_9_,
        avisopagam0_.varejo_id as varejo_11_9_ 
    from
        AvisoPagamento avisopagam0_ cross 
    join
        LoteAvisoPagamento loteavisop1_ 
    where
        1=1 
        and 1=1 
        and avisopagam0_.numeroAvisoPagamento=loteavisop1_.codigoAviso 
    order by dataAvisoPagamento desc
```

How can I count the records from Table Cobranca using TypedQuery and how can I fix this:

```
 where
            1=1 
            and 1=1
```

It's strange, I've been reading a lot about TypedQuery but I'm stuck

Comment: can u please put your models so we can help you

Comment: hi i've just posted my models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **ON** clause is working only with relations in JPA 2.1 release.

So mostly till now you can't use

**union with two columns: ON LoteAvisoPagamento.codigoAviso = AvisoPagamento.numeroAvisoPagamento**

because JPA 2.1 (last release) doesn't support that.

So it will not work on Criteria or JPQL

> **Note:** *CROSS JOIN* doesn't need *ON* clause, and that's why you are seeing it inside generated query also you can't do LEFT JOIN in
>   criteria with that way you are using (impossible) it will be always
>   generated as CROSS JOIN
>
> INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN needs a relation between entities

**Please** try next JPQL your side and test if it valid or not (and i think it will not work), it's simple but it should be similar to what you want to do(at least similar on one condition till now)

```
SELECT aviso.id, aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento, loteAviso.id
FROM AvisoPagamento aviso
LEFT JOIN LoteAvisoPagamento loteAviso 
ON loteAviso.codigoAviso = aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento
WHERE aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento = :numeroAviso
```

replace **:numeroAviso** with any valid value then test this as a entityManager.createQuery(**put here the query**)

Anyway i tested it my side for different entities but same logic and i got an exception as i expected

**note:** i am using *JPA* with *Hibernate* provider

and here are the exception i got

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

so it expecting something like that (which your entities doesn't support)

> LEFT JOIN aviso.loteAvisoPagamento loteAviso

in next query

```
SELECT aviso.id, aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento, loteAviso.id
FROM AvisoPagamento aviso
LEFT JOIN aviso.loteAvisoPagamento loteAviso
ON loteAviso.codigoAviso = aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento
WHERE aviso.numeroAvisoPagamento = :numeroAviso
```

Comment: hi @mibrahim.iti it's quite strange because this: final Predicate predicateLeftJoin = builder.equal(rootAviso.get("numeroAvisoPagamento"), rootLoteAviso.get("codigoAviso")); works properly but I was expecting LEFT JOIN not only JOIN

Comment: Ok, you can make edit to be LEFT JOIN but the main problem is the condition of ON clause, this is an example of how you can do LEFT JOIN >> Join<Supplier, Product> p = yourRoot.join(Supplier_.products, JoinType.LEFT); but it needs a relation and that's the problem

Comment: i will try to prepare a JPQL (simple one, because it's easier to do it quickly) to test what i am said, so if you even succeeded to convert it to LEFT JOIN the query will not work

Comment: i updated my answer please check the simple query in answer and test if it will work or not so you will be sure ON in JPA doesn't support working with no relations (Note: JPQL like Criteria in what they can do or not allowed to do)

Comment: Hi @mibrahim.iti  brilliant explanation, I got the same error : Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! As you told the LEFT or INNER JOIN needs relations betweens entities so my only solution is SQL Native.

Comment: yes unfortunately :( the only way for you now is using SQL native, so lets hope this can be done using JPQL and Criteria in next JPA release

Answer (score 0):

As @mibrahim.iti told the LEFT JOIN or INNER needs relations between entities so I used Native SQL to do this, here my final solution:

```
//Sql Log
        final StringBuilder sqlLog = new StringBuilder();
        sqlLog.append("select l from LogAvisoPagamento l where l.avisoPagamento.id = :idAviso  order by l.dataAcao ");

        final Query queryLog = manager.createQuery(sqlLog.toString());

        //Sql Aviso
        final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("select a.id, ")
        .append(" a.numeroAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.industria_id, ")
        .append(" a.varejo_id, ")
        .append(" a.dataAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.statusAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.dataUploadArquivo, ")
        .append(" a.dataImportacaoArquivo, ")
        .append(" a.dataConciliacaoAviso, ")
        .append(" count(c.avisoPagamento_id) as qtdeNotas, ")
        .append(" r.valorTotalBruto ")
        .append(" from AvisoPagamento a ")
        .append(" left join ResumoAvisoPagamento r ON r.avisoPagamento_id = a.id ")
        .append(" left join LoteAvisoPagamento l ON l.codigoAviso = a.numeroAvisoPagamento")
        .append(" left join Cobranca c ON c.avisoPagamento_id = l.id");

        boolean where = false;

        //Passou a Industria
        if (industria != null){
            sql.append(" where a.industria_id = :idIndustria");
            where = true;
        }

        //Passou o Varejo
        if (varejo != null){
            if (!where){
                sql.append(" where a.varejo_id = :idVarejo");
                where = true;
            }else{
                sql.append(" and a.varejo_id = :idVarejo");
            }
        }

        //Passou o numero do Aviso
        if (numeroAviso != null){
            if (!where){
                sql.append(" where a.numeroAvisoPagamennto = :numeroAvisoPagamento");
                where = true;
            }else{
                sql.append(" and a.numeroAvisoPagamento = :numeroAvisoPagamento");
            }

        }

        //Passou as Datas De e Ate
        if (dataDe != null && dataAte != null){
            if (!where){
                where = true;
                sql.append(" where a.dataAvisoPagamento between :dataDe and :dataAte");
            }else{
                sql.append(" and a.dataAvisoPagamento between :dataDe and :dataAte");
            }
        }

        sql.append(" group by a.id, a.numeroAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.numeroAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.industria_id, ")
        .append(" a.varejo_id, ")
        .append(" a.dataAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.statusAvisoPagamento, ")
        .append(" a.dataUploadArquivo, ")
        .append(" a.dataImportacaoArquivo, ")
        .append(" a.dataConciliacaoAviso, ")
        .append(" r.valorTotalBruto ");

        final Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());

        //Passou a Industria
        if (industria != null){
            query.setParameter("idIndustria", industria.getId());
        }

        //Passou o Varejo
        if (varejo != null){
            query.setParameter("idVarejo", varejo.getId());
        }

        //Passou o numero do Aviso
        if (numeroAviso != null){
            query.setParameter("numeroAvisoPagamento", numeroAviso);
        }

        //Passou as Datas De e Ate
        if (dataDe != null && dataAte != null){
            query.setParameter("dataDe", dataDe);
            query.setParameter("dataAte", dataAte);
        }

        final List<AvisoPagamento> avisosPagamentos = new ArrayList<AvisoPagamento>();
        //Percorrendo os Registros
        for (final Object array : query.getResultList()){

            final Object[] arrayAviso = (Object[]) array;

            final ResumoAvisoPagamento resumo = new ResumoAvisoPagamento();
            resumo.setValorTotalBruto((BigDecimal) arrayAviso[10]);

            final AvisoPagamento avisoPagamento = new AvisoPagamento();

            final BigInteger id = new BigInteger(arrayAviso[0].toString());
            avisoPagamento.setId(id.longValue());
            avisoPagamento.setNumeroAvisoPagamento((String) arrayAviso[1]);
            avisoPagamento.setDataAvisoPagamento((Date) arrayAviso[4]);
            avisoPagamento.setStatusAvisoPagamento(StatusAvisoPagamento.valueOf(arrayAviso[5].toString()));
            avisoPagamento.setDataUploadArquivo((Date) arrayAviso[6]);
            avisoPagamento.setDataImportacaoArquivo((Date) arrayAviso[7]);
            avisoPagamento.setDataConciliacaoAviso((Date) arrayAviso[8]);

            final BigInteger qtde = new BigInteger(arrayAviso[9].toString());
            avisoPagamento.setQtdeNotas(qtde.intValue());

            queryLog.setParameter("idAviso", avisoPagamento.getId());
            //Get Log
            final List<LogAvisoPagamento> logs = queryLog.getResultList();

            avisoPagamento.setLogAvisoPagamento(logs);
            avisoPagamento.setResumoAvisoPagamento(resumo);
            avisosPagamentos.add(avisoPagamento);
        }

        return avisosPagamentos;
```